# We need more algorithms!

Tags: identify-this-movie

There is an action movie that I saw a few years back where one of the characters was trying to hack something and blurted out

> WE NEED MORE ALGORITHMS!!!

I found hilarious because of how stupid it was, but unfortunately I dont remember what movie it was. I think it *may* have been one of the transformers, but I'm not sure.

Bonus points if you can post the scene as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was Stanley Tucci in [Transformers: Age of Extinction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2109248/?ref_=nv_sr_3). The scene is his scientists attempting to build their own transformers using technology they've taken from the transformers. Here's the clip:

Comment: Ah... looks like I misremembered the quote a bit.... still hilariously stupid though. Nice find.

Comment: I only knew it because my wife sent it to me after we watched the movie because we thought it was so hilarious!